# power series expansion at 0

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

How can I find the power series expansion of $f(z) = \sqrt{1-4z}$ at $0$?

I need to get the form: $\sum\nolimits_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. I tried to use the fact that the $a_n$ are of the form $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$, but this doesn't help me much. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Think Binomial expansion with $n=1/2$ and then take a derivative. That's a start but gets you pretty far.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$f'(x)=-2(1-4x)^{\frac12}=-2\times(f(x))^{-1}$$
$$f''(x)=-4(1-4x)^{\frac32}=-2\times2\times(f(x))^{-3}$$
$$f^{(3)}(x)=-24(1-4x)^{\frac52}=-4\times(2+4)\times(f(x))^{-5}$$
$$f^{(4)}(x)=-240(1-4x)^{\frac72}=-24\times(6+4)\times(f(x))^{-7}$$
$$f^{(5)}(x)=-3360(1-4x)^{\frac92}=-240\times(10+4)\times(f(x))^{-9}$$

Comment: @imranfat let me make it even more explicit then

Comment: Much appreciated...The OP needs the get the general form.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* for $|z|<1$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ is
\begin{align*}
(1+z)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n}z^n
\end{align*}

> Setting $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ we obtain for $|z|<\frac {1}{4}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sqrt{1-4z}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}(-4)^nz^n\\
> &=1-2z-2z^2-4z^3-10z^4-\cdots
> \end{align*}