# On which domain does the function $f(z) = \sqrt{1-4z}$ define a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

> We consider the function $f(z) = \sqrt{1-4z}$
>
> On which domain does the function $f$ define a holomorphic function?

I really do not know how to proceed with this one. I tried to solve it with the Cauchy-Riemann equation but miserably failed in splitting up the function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ first? You might be interested in [MSE question 2760471](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760471) power series expansion at 0.

Comment: Your first "function" should be "expression"